# "ssh-agent dwm" started from .xinitrc, but environment variables are not set

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, dwm

I got an `.xinitrc` file with the following line:

```
# it will start my window manager
ssh-agent dwm
```

After that I got an `ssh-agent` process, but environment variables like
`$SSH_AGENT_PID` and
`$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`
does not exists when I start a terminal from `dwm`. Any ideas why?

I wish there was only one `ssh-agent` process. Each call to `ssh-add` should connect to the agent that started `dwm`.

Answer (score -1):

`ssh-agent` outputs the environment variables you need to have to connect to it, by calling `eval` you immediately load those variables into your environment.

Why `ssh-agent` can't do that itself?

> In Unix, a process can only modify its own environment variables, and pass them on to children. It can not modify its parent process' environment because the system won't allow it. This is pretty basic security design.

In relation to it read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351725/why-eval-the-output-of-ssh-agent).

Therefore, leave your `.xinitrc as:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) &
exec dwm
```

Comment: You should check `man ssh-agent`. The agent can act as a wrapper to other programs and exports the right variables to them, no need for eval in that case. If you don't believe me, make sure you don't have an agent running and then run `ssh-agent bash`. You'll find that the bash session has a running agent.

Answer (score -1):

In your `.xinitrc`, dwm should be called with exec. The following sets up an agent for dwm for me:

```
exec ssh-agent dwm
```

Running startx and then opening a terminal shows the agent loaded.

Comment: The only reason to use `exec` here is that it's unnecessary to have the shell hang around waiting for `dwm` to exit.  There is no requirement to use `exec` for `ssh-agent` to do the right thing.  This answer points out how one _usually_ writes the `.xinitrc` file, but it does not explain why the `dwm` process does not propagate the correct environment variables to e.g. terminals etc. started as child processes from the window manager.

Comment: @Kusalananda Why would I explain that dwm fails to propagate env, when it's my claim that in fact the env is correctly propagated using my method? If the person asking the question launched dwm in the way it is meant to be launched, they wouldn't have the problem, right? Of course, feel free to post the _true_ answer, if you know a better way.

Comment: Since both `ssh-agent util` and `exec ssh-agent util` sets the appropriate `ssh`-related environment variables for `util ` (the latter, with `exec`, only replaces the calling shell, there is no other difference), and since `ssh-agent util` does not seem to work for the user in this question when `util` is `dwm`, we must conclude that there is something that _removes_ the environment variables between the execution of the SSH agent and whatever command they use to look at the environment in `dwm`.  No manner of adding `exec` or not adding `exec` to the `ssh-agent` command will change that.

Comment: In other words: You seem to be saying that `exec ssh-agent dwn` _will work_ when `ssh-agent dwm` (without `exec`) evidently does not work.  Such a claim would need to be explained as `exec` in itself does not change the way that the `ssh`-related variables are propagated into the environment of `dwm`.